# DJango - The view accounts.decorators.loginview didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am building an account app and have built a decorator for anonymous users only. I can log into django through the app however if i enter data wrong it returns

```
The view accounts.decorators.loginview didn't return an HttpResponse object.    It returned None instead.
```

no where in my code does it redirect any urls etc to this non-existent view

decorator.py

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def anonymous_required(function=None, home_url=None, redirect_field_name=None):
def _dec(view_func):
    def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            url = None
            if redirect_field_name and redirect_field_name in request.REQUEST:
                url = request.REQUEST[redirect_field_name]
            if not url:
                url = home_url
            if not url:
                url = "/"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    _view.__name__ = view_func.__name__
    _view.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
    _view.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__

    return _view

if function is None:
    return _dec
else:
    return _dec(function)
```

how i authenticate users

```py
@anonymous_required(home_url='/')
def loginview(request):
"""
View for login page
"""
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            django_login(request, user)
            if request.GET.get('next') is not None and request.GET.get('next') != '':
                return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
            else:
                return redirect('/')
else:
    return render(request, "login.tpl", {})
```

its probably something small i missed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current login view doesn't account for invalid form data or invalid user. Drop the else and move the `redirect('/')` out of your `if form.is_valid()`.

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        django_login(request, user)
        if request.GET.get('next') is not None and request.GET.get('next') != '':
            return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
return redirect('/')
```